# Freeze application on Set dynamic image selector

Tags: android, android-layout

```
I need to set Selector dynamically
```

I took help from this [How to set an image as a Background to a Button using StateListDrawable (dynamically or programmatically or through code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132047/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-to-a-button-using-statelistdrawable-dynamic/33940506#33940506)

When i try to set default image  its not working

```
state.addState(new int[] { },selectedthumb);
```

Please help me

**What i have tried**

```
StateListDrawable state = new StateListDrawable();
state.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected },
                        selectedthumb);
state.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused },  thumb);

state.addState(new int[] {  },thumb);
```

Comment: what is your selectedthumb?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani  Drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void selector(Button b,int selectedthumb,int thumb)
    {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        states.addState(new int[] {- android.R.attr.state_pressed }, getResources().getDrawable(selectedthumb));
        states.addState(new int[] {}, getResources().getDrawable(thumb));
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368765/3593066) You need to use the negative value of the needed state. E.g.:

```
states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled},R.drawable.btn_disabled);
```